# Firebase Hosting, create a 404 page

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I'm using Firebase to host a domain with some static html, javascript and images. It works great. The last thing I want to do, is creating a custom 404-error page. According to the Firebase Hosting Documentation ([link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/url-redirects-rewrites)) I only have to put a file called '404.html' inside the project public directory. It doesn't work. A tree view of my project directory:

- 404.html
- index.html
- images (directory)
- robots.txt

My **firebase.json** file looks like this:

```js
{
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "domain.com",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your source is:

```
"source": "**"
```

This causes all routes to go to the index.html file. Since all routes go there, it will never throw a 404. If you want the 404 to work, you must specify the routes that actually work. ie:

```
"source": "/"
```

Comment: I changed "source": "**" to "source": "/", restarted Firebase by typing "firebase serve" in the terminal and it worked like a charm! Thanks.

Comment: I think they should add this specification in the docs. I don't know why they didn't, the firebase doc is pretty good.